# Nested If / Else in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I am very new to any coding, so please bear with me if this seems basic.

I am trying to allocate the appropriate greeting in an email with the variable $fname. The data that the name values originate from is a simple, single string. The possible variations in format are therefore numerous.

In this particular application, the details are mostly written as either:

-Mr John Smith
-Mr Smith
-John Smith
-John

I therefore need to evaluate the method used to enter the name before I can allocate it to the variable.

I have written the follow code, but online checking throws up "an unexpected 'else'".

It all seems right to me and the online examples I have looked at seem to follow a similar order.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Rob.

**OK - edited again with correct, actual tested working code. (I was tired yesterday and missed a possible outcome) This definitely works for all the permutations that I need. Hopefully it will save some other beginner the insane amount of time it took me to do something so simple!**

Thanks again to everybody who helped and apologies for my total 'newbie'ness.

```
 <?php

    $saltest = explode(" ", $client);

    if (empty($saltest[1])) {  // checks to see if it a single name eg 'John'.
    $fname = $saltest[0];

    } elseif (isset($saltest[1])) { // if it is not a single word, checks to see if starts with a salutation
    switch ($saltest[0]) {
        case 'Mr';
        case 'Mrs';
        case 'Ms';
        case 'Mr.';
        case 'Mrs.';
        case 'Ms.';
        case 'Dr';
        case 'Dr.';
        $withsal = $saltest;    // if it does, allocate the array to variable $withsal.
    break;
        default: $withoutsal = $saltest; // if it doesn't - allocate it to variable $withoutsal.
        break;
    }
    }
    if (isset($withoutsal)) { // if already established that there is no salutation, issue the $fname & $lname variables
    $fname = $withoutsal[0];
    $lname = $withoutsal[1];
    } elseif (isset($withsal) and isset($withsal[2])) { // if it has a salutation and is compised of 3 words - issue $fname & $lname accordingly.
    $fname = $withsal[1];
    $lname = $withsal[2];   
    } elseif (isset($withsal) and isset($withsal[1])) { // if it has a salutation but is only 2 words, put them together to create variable $fname eg. "Mr Smith" and declare the $lname variable as NULL. It is not needed. 
    $fname = implode(" ", $withsal);
    $lname = NULL;  
    }
    echo $fname;

    ?>
```

Comment: `if {...} else {...} else {...}`, when will the third block be executed?

Comment: You need to add expressions into your else statements: `elseif(expression)`...

Comment: add closing bracket , Your else is not closed.

Comment: Biffen: If...if...else...else...if...else...

If the first if is correct, but not the second.

Comment: @RobKane Not the way you wrote it. You'll need more brackets for that. Start by indenting your code properly. And get an editor that can show you matching brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `else` statement after another `else`. You need to either get an `if` statement between them, or you want to use `elseif`. According to your comment. (`// but if there was no salutation and only 2 names were given...`) You need to change to `elseif`

Answer (score 0):

There are some brackets missing

```
<?php
    // splits the name field into parts
    $names = explode(" ", $client);

    // works out if the name field starts with a salutation
    if ($names[0] == ("Mr" || "Mrs" || "Ms" || "Mr." || "Mrs." || "Ms.")) 
    {
     // decides if it is written as "Salutation, surname"
        if (empty($names[2])) 
        {
            $lname = $names[1];
            $salname = array($names[0], $names[1]);
            $fname = implode(" ", $salname);
    // evaluates that if it starts with a salutation and has 3 names, it must then be "salutation firstname lastname"
        } 
        else 
        {        
            $fname = $names[1];
            $lname = $names[2];
        // but if there was no salutation and only 2 names were given...
        }
    } 
    else 
    {        
        if (empty(names[2])) 
        {
            $fname = $names[0];
            $lname = $names[1];
        // otherwise it must be "first, middle, last"
        } 
        else 
        {        
            $fname = $names[0];
            $lname = $names[3];
        }
    }
?>
```